# Azure Websites SSO using ADFS

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service, adfs

There is a Web Application develpoed in `ASP.NET` and deployed on `Azure Websites`. SSO login is provided using ADFS authentication. Log-in username is required to be stored in one of the Audit Columns in the database table.
First I tried below code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;

ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
string fullname = cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
```

It works fine when deployed on On-Premise IIS but throws null exception when deployed on Azure Websites.

I also tried:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

It also works fine on On-Premise but shows  `"IIS APPPOOL\<AppName>"` when deployed on Azure Websites.

Comment: I don't think it is very clear what you are asking, can you edit your question to be clearer?

Comment: The latter won't work, it is intented to show the identity of the process, not the logged user. The former should work, assuming that you have set up your sso correctly.