# Headline steps required to extend an existing (Azure based) ASP.NET forms auth app to use ADFS

Tags: asp.net, azure, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an existing ASP.NET app deployed on Azure. It has its own auth system, essentially a u/p database table and creation of a forms auth cookie:

```
    public void LogIn(LoginDetails userLogin, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        var info = (CustomPrincipalInfo) userLogin;
        var timeout = 30;

        if (createPersistentCookie)
            timeout = 60*24;

        var cookie = info.CreateAuthenticationCookie(DateTime.Now, timeout, createPersistentCookie);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    public static HttpCookie CreateAuthenticationCookie(this CustomPrincipalInfo info, DateTime current, int timeout, bool remember)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var userData = serializer.Serialize(info);
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1, info.Email, current, current.AddMinutes(timeout), remember, userData);

        var secureTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, secureTicket) { Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain };
        if (remember)
            cookie.Expires = current.AddMinutes(timeout);
        return cookie;
    }
```

Most of the customers just register details, log in using their details with us etc, but we've been asked to integrate with a customer that uses ADFS for SSO. My reading around the topic suggests that we need to run an ADFS server, integrate our app with it, and then engage in a process of establishing trust between their ADFS server and ours

I'm curious to know if, given that it's hosted on Azure already, there is anything we can do with Azure/AAD to skip the "run an ADFS server" part, because we don't really have any infrastructure for doing so. The app startup routine is older school Global.asax style, using castle windsor for DI/IoC:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DependencyRegistrar.Register();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        InitializeInfrastructure();
        MigrateDatabaseSchema();
        
        DataAnnotationConfig.RegisterValidationAttributes();

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles();
    }
```

The resources I'm turning up are generally older stuff:

- [ADFS with existing ASP.Net MVC App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463956/adfs-with-existing-asp-net-mvc-app) - this mentions [a separate blog](https://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) discussing server 2012r2 in depth - we do have such a sevrer, but are looking to retire it rather than add another reason to carry on using it/have to replace it with a newer one
- [Azure Websites SSO using ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855136/azure-websites-sso-using-adfs) brought up [an azure sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation) that seems to imply Azure can help us avoid having to run a dedicated ADFS server, but again the sample is ~9 years old

[The most recent one I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310356/asp-net-application-sso-with-adfs?rq=1) seemed to be a reasonable description of the problem I face, but I couldn't understand the answer (which basically seemed to be "read this link, scroll down a bit" - reading the link didn't smack me in the face with anything obviously "this is what you have to do")

[Resources surrounding using ADFS on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/how-to-connect-fed-azure-adfs) seem massively involved; I don't feel like I need/want/to pay for load balancers, multiple storage accounts, DMZs and proxies etc.. This is literally so that one user at one customer can sign in a handful of times a month

What set of steps do I take to create a really basic ADFS SSO auth mechanism in this existing app, hook in to how it IDs users so that when joe.bloggs@customer.com comes and signs in via ADFS I can become aware of the email address that is signed in and give him his forms auth cookie like anyone else, and leverages some Azure based facility so that I don't have to run an ADFS server?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The basic problem is that your credentials are in a DB and neither AAD nor ADFS supports this.

You could run [identityserver4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in Azure and configure idsrv4 to authenticate against the DB. Then you could federate idsrv4 with the partner ADFS.

Or you could move the users into Azure AD via the Graph API and then federate AAD with ADFS.

Comment: Hi Rory, a follow-up question on this if you will: I've succeeded in creating a test ADFS, an idsrv4 impl and a client of it, it's all hooked up and the client passes through to idsrv4's login page, which successfully goes to ADFS and back, but I don't understand how to make idsrv4 tell the client who signed in. idsrv4's code knows (it puts domainx\userx on its login page) but the claims the client gets from idsrv4 don't seem to relate to the ADFS user at all. What am I not understanding here?If idsrv4 knows the ADFS identifiers, how should it tell the client who signed in/their roles etc?

Comment: When you federated with ADFS, what protocol did you use? In ADFS, you have to configure the claims you want to be returned and then you would have to map them to the idsrv4 claims. e.g. if you used SAML or WS-Fed for the federation, then the email claim from ADFS would be something like http://....claims/email. You would have to map this to the idsrv4 claim called email.

Comment: SAML. Ahh, I think I just had the lightbulb moment.. idsrv4 is signed in with ADFS, the client is signed in with idsrv4, idsrv4 got a bunch of claims that were useful from ADFS but the sample code essentially throws them all away (and much sooner than I was looking when debugging) when it set up the claims for the idsrv<-->client leg so I never realised it was getting the email back. So my last remaining question is, I guess, what's the best way to connect this old ASP.NET app to auth with idsrv4? The old app uses forms auth and roles extensively and I don't want to disturb that atm, I'd ...

Comment: ... rather tack a bit onto it so it can do an auth process with idsrv4, get the email back and then use that in the existing "this user with email x just used their password successfully, create a Forms auth ticket y for them" - I've been struggling to find examples for how to connect old asp.net apps to idsrv4- everything seems to assume that IHostBuilder is available and can say eg `app.UseIdentityServer()` but this older app has a Global.asax rather than Startup/Configure etc - (I'm just looking at the older idsrv3 samples to see if anything helpful is in them)

Comment: Maybe find an older OIDC library?